# Ensure single instance of a WPF application : Difficulty restoring the already running application to the foreground

Tags: c#, wpf

**Intention** : Run a **single instance** of a WPF application. When a new instance, is started the already running instance should be set to the foreground.

While I have **achieved most** of it, I am facing a problem when the already running application is sitting in the notification tray. The code runs without an error, but fails to restore the window & set it to foreground. **Code Snippet (c#):**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

string processName = currentProcess.ProcessName;
Process[] instances = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

if (instances.Length > 1)
{
    foreach(var instance in instances)
    {
        if (!currentProcess.Id.Equals(instance.Id))
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = instance.MainWindowHandle;

            if (IsIconic(hWnd))
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);

            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        }
    }
    currentProcess.Kill();
}
```

Can any one point out what am I doing wrong. To reiterate again, it works in the case when the already running window is in maximized state but in the hindsight. It fails when the already running window is minimized to the notification tray.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified, that your code executes the `ShowWindow` when the already running process is in the systray? I am asking, because I don't think that `IsIconic` is the correct function to use: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that it "determines whether the specified window is minimized". If the process is in the systray it isn't minimized, it is hidden.

I think you should use [`IsWindowVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.